# Change date format in Swift

Tags: date, swift2

I have a date format in `String` value of "2015-08-27" which is "YYYY-MM-DD". I need to convert this to `Date` format and change the format to "DD-MMM-YYYY". And change it back to `String` format again to display. So the end result would be "27-AUG-2015".

I have been searching for codes, but couldn't find one.

Answer (score 9):

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString("2015-08-27")

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "DD-MMM-YYYY"
let goodDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date!)
```

Its not tested but I hope it will work.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a class helper like DateHelper and class func:

```
class func convertDateString(dateString : String!, fromFormat sourceFormat : String!, toFormat desFormat : String!) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = sourceFormat
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = desFormat
    return dateFormatter.string(from: date!)
}
```

And use it:(note format you give on question wrong so it will wrong convert): begin format is YYYY-MM-dd and you want convert to dd-MMM-YYYY)

```
print(DateHelper.convertDateString("2015-08-27", fromFormat: "YYYY-MM-dd", toFormat: "dd-MMM-YYYY"))
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

Just used the function in your code(swift 4.2).

```
public func convertDateFormatter(date: String) -> String {
 let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"//this your string date format
 dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC") as TimeZone!
 dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "your_loc_id")
 let convertedDate = dateFormatter.date(from: date)
 guard dateFormatter.date(from: date) != nil else {
 assert(false, "no date from string")
 return ""
 }
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm a"///this is what you want to convert format
 dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC") as TimeZone!
 let timeStamp = dateFormatter.string(from: convertedDate!)
 print(timeStamp)
 return timeStamp
 }
```

Thanks